# Reverse for "URL" with arguments '(id)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 'URL< int:ID >'

Tags: django

I'm stock with this error i can't get the "id" of my list i get an error. i'm trying to crete an UPDATE button to edit the data i add to my database.

Here's my 
views.py in my apps

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from gomo_web_system.forms import UserForm,NewMasterForm

    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from gomo_web_system.models import masterList

    from django.contrib import messages


def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'gomo_web_system/main_menu.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'gomo_web_system/index.html', context)

def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

@login_required
def main_menu(request):
    return render(request, 'gomo_web_system/main_menu.html')

@login_required
def it_home(request):
    return render(request, 'gomo_web_system/IT/it_home.html')

@login_required
def it_master_list(request):
    master_list = masterList.objects.order_by('projectName')
    master_dict = {'master':master_list}
    return render(request, 'gomo_web_system/IT/it_master_list.html', context=master_dict)

@login_required
def it_create_master_list(request):

    form = NewMasterForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print('printring POST:', request.POST)
        form = NewMasterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('gomotion:master_list')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'gomo_web_system/IT/it_add_master_list.html', context)

def it_update_master_list(request, id):
    form = NewMasterForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'gomo_web_system/IT/it_add_master_list.html', context)
```

Here's my in my apps
myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from gomo_web_system import views

app_name = 'gomotion'

urlpatterns = [
    url('main/',views.main_menu, name="main"),
    url('itHome/',views.it_home, name="home"),
    url('itMasterList/', views.it_master_list, name="master_list"),
    url('itAddMasterList/',views.it_create_master_list, name="add_master_list"),
    url('itUpdateMasterList/<int:id>/',views.it_update_master_list, name="update_master_list"),
]
```

Here's my in my apps
urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from gomo_web_system import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    path('gomoadmin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('gomotion/', include('gomo_web_system.urls')),

]
```

this file get the .id error in "master_list.id" bold text

```
{% extends 'gomo_web_system/IT/it_base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block it_base %}

<!-- Card section -->
<!-- Title row -->
<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10 py-5">
    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <h3><span class="text-uppercase text-danger ">MASTER LIST</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'gomotion:add_master_list' %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block text-uppercase mb-2">Add Project</a>
    <table id="master_list_table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <!-- table Head -->
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">MASTER</th>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">PROJECTS</th>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">YEAR</th>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">SERIAL</th>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">FORMAT</th>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">SPACE</th>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">BYTES</th>
          <th scope="col" class-"text-muted">ACTIONS</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
          <!-- table body -->

      <tbody>
          {% for master_list in master %}
        <tr>
          <td class="text-uppercase">{{ master_list.masterName }}</td>
          <td class="text-uppercase"><a href="#">{{ master_list.projectName }}</a></td>
          <td class="text-uppercase">{{ master_list.year }}</td>
          <td class="text-uppercase">{{ master_list.serialNumber }}</td>
          <td class="text-uppercase">{{ master_list.hdFormat }}</td>
          <td class="text-uppercase">{{ master_list.space }}</td>
          <td class="text-uppercase">{{ master_list.hdBytes }}</td>
          **<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'gomotion:update_master_list' master_list.id %}">update</a></td>**
        </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </tbody>

    </table>


<!-- End of colum -->
</div>
<!-- end of table -->


{% endblock %}
```

Here's the error i recieved. 
[image]

Comment: Please share with us `update_master_list`.

Comment: there's no html file with update master it will directly to my add _master_list

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the instance which you need to update, to the view.

```
def it_update_master_list(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(masterList, id=id)
    form = NewMasterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return redirect('/')
        context = {'form':form, "instance": instance,}
        return render(request, 'your_form.html', context)
```

Comment: hi sir the error is is my html file when i put the  "master_list.id" in my html file i get an error. there's the code **<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'gomotion:update_master_list' master_list.id %}">update</a></td>**
        </tr>

Comment: yes your update view is incorrect, correct it as shown and see still error is there

Comment: <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'gomotion:update_master_list' %}?yourID={{master_list.id}} %}">update</a></td> </tr>

Comment: <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'gomotion:update_master_list' %}?yourID={{master_list.id}}">update</a></td> </tr>

Comment: your create view works? i have updated the edit view, check and reply

Comment: @bmons hi sir actually my error is in the html file when i put the master_list.id in {% url %} i get the error.